# Pyside program locks up in response to a checkbox click

Tags: python, qt4, pyside

I am having a very strange problem. Whenever the QCheckBox is checked it calls drawall as expected. However when drawall is finished it completely hangs. I have tried directly calling drawall (Version 2) when clicked but with no luck the result is the same.

```
scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 500, 500)

class SurrogateBeat(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self,beat,top):
        super(SurrogateBeat, self).__init__()
        print "Init"

class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.drawAll = QCheckBox("Draw all frames on screen",self)
        self.drawAll.stateChanged.connect(self.onDrawAllClicked)

    def onDrawAllClicked(self):                #Version 1
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.drawall)

    def onDrawAllClicked(self):                #Version 2 (neither work)
        self.drawall()

    def drawall(self):
        if self.drawAll.checkState() ==  Qt.CheckState.Checked: 
            self.surrogates=[]
            for b in range(0,len(self.item.beats)):
                print "Loop"
                surrogate = SurrogateBeat(b, self.item)
                scene.addItem(surrogate)
                self.surrogates.append(surrogate)
            scene.update()
            print "Update"
```

Loop prints out 16 times, the **init** for SurrogateBeat prints out so it is being called, but after "Update" prints out, the program is hung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`QGraphicsItem`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qgraphicsitem.html) is an abstract base class.

As a minimum, your `SurrogateBeat` subclass will need to reimplement the [`boundingRect`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) and [`paint`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) functions.

Comment: Thank you I had already re-implemented the paint function but forgot about bounding rect. This fixes it completely.